# How is threat determined in Dark Heresy?

Tags: combat, dark-heresy-1e, warhammer-40k

In Dark Heresy, you can gain a bonus to your melee attacks if you outnumber an opponent two to one or three to one.  Are opponents threatened if a player is next to them or do they have to have previously taken a combat action against that foe? (Threat does not seem to be well defined from what I've read so far.)  Can a player contribute towards outnumbering a foe if they are threatened by multiple enemies at once?

I have a preference to RAW (rules as written) answers on this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You count as being Engaged if you are within melee range of the thing in question and are in combat**

and

**There's nothing RAW that says you can't contribute to outnumbering one foe even if you yourself are engaged with many other foes**

There's not really a hard rule as to what counts as being engaged, so we have to apply some common sense here. Basically, if you're within range of attacking or being attacked by a melee combatant, you're considered "engaged" with them, and subject to the ganging up rule.

Let's take a quick look at the rules for fleeing from combat:

> **Disengage (Full Action)**
>
> You break off from melee combat and may move up to your Half Move
>   rate. Opponents whom you were engaged with do not gain the customary
>   free attacks. p. 192

And the rules for ganging up:

> **Ganging Up**
>
> You have an advantage when you and your allies engage the same foe in
>   melee combat. [...] p. 198

So we've established that you have to be in melee combat in order to benefit from the gang up rules. I propose 3 guidelines to determine if you are indeed threatening an opponent:

1. Can I smack the enemy?
2. If I were to run, would they get to smack me?
3. Is it trying to kill me?

Keep in mind that Dark Heresy is a very abstract game, so if it makes sense, run with it.

Comment: Thanks for giving as much RAW as possible and filling in with supporting opinion.